# Запятая перед "типа"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "типа" в предложениях вроде:
"Это красный камень(,) типа граната" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указанная запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая ставится в зависимости от смысла.
Если "типа граната" входит в определение (По вашему запросу сообщаю, что представленный образец это красный камень типа граната), то запятая не нужна.
Если же автор "типа граната" означает сравнение - или, скажем, неуверенность автора в точной классификациии, - то это скорее всего пояснение, запятая как минимум факльтативна:  "Кажется, это красный камень(,) типа граната, но какой-то необычный, возможно искусственный". В последнем случае я бы запятую поставил.

Answer (score 1):

я думаю, запятая в предложениях подобной структуры должна ставится, так как здесь подразумевается сравнение, сопоставление предметов по цвету. Просторечный союз "типа" можно заменить - "наподобие", "подобный". 
Можно рассмотреть и как пояснение, как уточняющий член предложения- определение (камень какой? - типа граната. В этом случае также необходима запятая.
Если бы предложение было построено несколько иначе: вместо "это" было бы местоимение "этот", то запятая бы не ставилась:"Этот красный камень типа граната..." - требуется продолжение предложения.